# time axis confusion in signals and systems

Tags: signal-processing, time

I am learning signals and systems and we are given a impulse response swhich is discrete and from -5 to +5 on X axis.

I do not really understand that it has a negative part as everything starts from 0 or some positive number(assuming you delayed your experiment).

Some signals also have negative parts which a bit troubles me. I do not understand how to make sense of time axis in this course.

Comment: not every signal is causal. you can't assume that – full stop.

Comment: I think of "0" as an arbitrary point in time that's used as a reference. For example, my oscilloscope may have a point labeled 0 but it's just the point at which it triggered and labeled that point in time as zero. If you have a node that's sitting at ground for a long time and then an impulse is somehow injected onto that node, we might pick the impulse point as time = 0 and then work the math around that as opposed to take, say an hour before that and call that 0.

Comment: talk to your teacher about your uncertainty ... maybe you missed something important in your lessons

Comment: You are right, there are no signals like this in reality.  Sometimes by pretending things exist, it makes the mathematical models of how things work simpler and more straightforward. That is why, for example, this kind of signal is used in your textbook. After analyzing this situation, you will learn how to modify the math to analyze a signal that really can exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most comments have pointed out: a causal system only has non-zero values for \$t > 0\$, while non-causal systems can be non-zero at \$t < 0\$. Causal means that the output can only depend on the current input and its past. Causal systems are what you'll typically find with real-time circuits, where it is impossible to *look into the future*.

Non-causal systems can be found typically in signal processing applications where you have access to all the data beforehand. Typical "real-world" examples would be processing images in X- and Y-direction, or audio processing of pre-recorded material.

You can think of it as using data left and right of the current point to determine our output value rather than only the left side or past input.